# Regarding ManyToManyFields in Django

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

Suppose I make a model:

```
class A(models.Model):
       col = models.ManyToManyField(B)
```

Now after migration, this will create a table A_B with fields id,A_id,B_id.
Now if I want to access the id of the table A_B, how to do that? And how to update the B_id of this table?

Comment: Why would you need `B_id`? You can just access B from the otherside like B.col_set (or similar)? Can you give your models *actual* names, so we understand what you are trying to model?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Through Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

```
class A(models.Model):
       col = models.ManyToManyField(B, through='C')

class C(models.Model):
      a = models.ForeignKey(A)
      b = models.ForeignKey(B)
      //any other extra field
```

Then you can filter or query `C` table.

For example, to print all `C` instances `id`:

```
for c in C.objects.all():
     print c.id
```

Comment: Can't I do it without using a Through Relationship?

Comment: @PriyanshGoel You will need raw SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object of A:

```
A_obj.col.all()
```

This will return all the A_B objects related to that A

```
for ab in A_obj.col.all():
   print ab.id
```

This will print all the ids of the table A_B.

```
for ab in A_obj.col.all():
    ab.B_id = new id
    ab.save()
```

This will update your B_id with new id.